# Failed to load resource 404 style.css firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Receiving the following console log from my static website

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

on `style.css`

Project structure

root - `home.html`
folder inside root - `styles`
file inside 'styles' folder - `style.css`

(It's a simple website, for testing firebase)

I've used firebase to create the instance of my website and it outputted my html to a public folder with `index.html` but no css files.

Like so `public/index.html`

I've added inline css to account for this by using `<style media="screen">` and it works but it's still not reading/finding my style.css file

`style.css` link inside `index.html` (firebase created)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/style.css">
```

Looked into other answers but they're using bootstrap supplied cdn/url. I want to be able to use the one I created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase hosting will only host the files under your [`public` folder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying#public). Which means that your `style` folder is not being uploaded and thus `index.html` can't detect the css file.

You need to move your style folder to have it inside the public folder and change the link to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
```

Comment: Yes, firebase deploy let's you choose a root context (/public/ by default). I think this answer is exactly right.

Comment: This worked - although I don't see why firebase didn't compile all my files instead of having to do this manually. Was this an error on my side when initialising or is there a way to build and deploy all files at once? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, when you initialize your project in the Firebase CLI, it asks which folder do you want to use as a public folder. And the default folder is named "public" (as @KevinCaravaggio mentioned). But that should be fine if you simply move your files to the folder named public.

Comment: Yes, and also to add to this answer, I faced the same issue when I added all of my styles and scripts to the public folder.
But when I separated the files within the public folder where the style folder contains CSS files and the script folder contains JS files, it worked for me.